# How to obtain projection type from matplotlib.pyplot.axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making an app that plots out the same data on a 3D plot and 2D plot within the same figure but on difference axes.
To create the axis I have

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax3d = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax2d = fig.add_subplot(212)
```

I am writing a function which plots the data on both the axes, but due to the nature of the plots, the function has to take into consideration the projection type of the axes. How do i retrieve the `'3d'`/`'2d'` from `ax3d`/`ax2d`, or something of the same effect? Given that `ax3d.projection` is not a valid attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case, the `name` attributes of `ax2d` and `ax3d` will include `rectilinear` and `3d` respectively. You can use that attribute to differentiate between the different axes types.

```
>>> '3d' in ax3d.name 
True
>>> '3d' in ax2d.name
False
>>> 'rectilinear' in ax2d.name
True
>>> 'rectilinear' in ax3d.name
False
```